# Passing parameters to function before this.control() in Ext-JS 4

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have this:

```
{
    listeners['combobox[name="counterparty_id"]'] = {
        afterrender: {
            fn: this.onComboboxCounterpartyAfterrender,
            scope: this
        }
    };      

    this.control(listeners);
}



// function which is being called after rendering the combobox

onComboboxCounterpartyAfterrender: function(combobox, eOpts){

// some code

},
```

So, how can I send additional parameteres to `onComboboxCounterpartyAfterrender` function?

Maybe something like this:

```
listeners['combobox[name="counterparty_id"]'] = {
            afterrender: {
                fn: this.onComboboxCounterpartyAfterrender,
                scope: this,
                params: someParameters
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a better way, but you can do:

```
listeners['combobox[name="counterparty_id"]'] = {
    afterrender: {
        fn: function(combobox, eOpts) {
            this.onComboboxCounterpartyAfterrender(combobox, eOpts, params)
        }
        ...
```

Comment: It's a very nice idea. I'll try it later if there is no "conventional" way of doing this. If not, I'll mark your answer as correct. And thank you. :)

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to do this.

First, you can use eOpts. As documentation states, eOpts is "The options object passed to Ext.util.Observable.addListener.". So in your example, you should be able to do ePots.params to access someParametsrs

Second, you can use Ext.bind() or Ext.pass() to pass your parameters. First one prepends, 2nd one appends additional arguments.

Thirdly, you can do what Amit Aviv suggested, this is pretty much what Ext.pass() would do.

Fourthly, you could use scopes, if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your briefly explained answer. You answer teaches me more and shows much more options but I think @Amit Aviv's answer is simpler and better for my problem so his answer will be marked as "correct". Nevermind, here is a +1 for teaching me something new. :) Thank you.